# Динамический вывод данных об отправке e-mail сообщений

Tags: ajax, php, рассылка, email

Есть простой скрипт рассылки, который в цикле парсит txt-файл с базой адресов и отправляет сообщения по 1 шт. Отправлять сразу все - не вариант. Также скрипт выводит на страницу информацию о результате каждой отправки. Но в силу особенностей взаимодействия, данные выводятся только после отправки ВСЕХ сообщений. Такой расклад меня не устраивает, поскольку до окончания рассылки о ее состоянии мне ничего не известно (кому отправилось и отправилось ли вообще). Нужно реализовать отображение этих данных в реальном времени. Т.е. сервер отправил первое сообщение - на экране появилась уведомление, отправил второе - ещё уведомление и т.д. Как это сделать? Буду очень благодарен за развернутый ответ. Спасибо.
Текущий скрипт выглядит примерно так:

```
//Тут было формирование текста сообщения
$filename = "База.txt";
if(file_exists($filename))
{
    $database = fopen($filename, "r");
    while(!feof($database))
    {
        $to = chop(fgets($database, 4096));
        $isSuccess = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
        echo date('h:i:s')." ";
        if($isSuccess) echo $to.' Письмо отправлено'.'<br/>'; else echo $to.' Письмо не отправлено'.'<br/>';
    }      
    fclose($database);
}
```

UPD: реализовал посредством вызова с главной страницы через Ajax(jQuery) php-скрипта рассылки, записывающего рез-т в txt-файл и затем, снова через Ajax, вызова php-парсера, который эти данные возвращает на основную страницу. Всем спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Ответом на Ваш вопрос будет AJAX. Или нужно расписать как это все реализовать на Javascript?

Comment: У меня мало опыта по части JS/AJAX, посему было бы здорово расписать, если вам не в тягость.

Answer (score 3):

Сделай два скрипта: один вот почту отправляет и выводит сообщения в какой-нибудь файл, а не в обычный поток вывода, а второй читает этот файл и отправляет его в браузер.

На странице HTML в двух ифреймах запусти оба скрипта и пока в первом происходит отправка почты, во втором просто смотри, что выводится в тот файл. Либо запрашивай содержимое этого файла аяксом.

Весьма дешёвый вариант реализации.

Comment: Немного не то, но спасибо за наводку - прочитав ваш совет, придумал в принципе неплохой метод реализации.

Comment: Мой ответ вас устраивает?