# Динамический вывод данных PHP скрипта в процессе его выполнения

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

Есть `html`-страница с формой отправки данных PHP скрипту.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="form">
<textarea placeholder="Введите число" name="num" rows="1" cols="45" required></textarea></br>
<p><input value="Отправить" type="submit"></p></form>
<div id="content"></div>

<script>
$(function(){
  'use strict';
$('#form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var fd = new FormData( this );
    $.ajax({
      url: 'sen.php',
      type: 'POST',
      contentType: false, 
      processData: false, 
      data: fd,
      success:function(html){  
$("#content").html(html);
 }  
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

PHP скрипт просто умножает число полученное из формы в цикле. '*Засыпая*' на одну секунду после вывода значения.

```
<?php
$num = $_POST['num'];
for ($i = 1; $i < 4; $i++) {
    echo $i*$num."<br/>";
    sleep(1);
  }
?>
```

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы значения выводились на `html`-странице после каждого `sleep`'a. А не тогда, когда скрипт просчитает все значения? Нашел очень много подобных вопросов, даже манипуляции с `flush()`. Но должен же быть адекватный метод? Что-то мне подсказывает что без `Ajax(jQuery)` не обойтись, и подобное человек делал тут [Динамический вывод данных об отправке e-mail сообщений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/322701/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BE%D0%B1-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B5-e-mail-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9), но к сожалению он не описал своего решения. Но я не силён в `Ajax(jQuery)`, чтобы справится с этим как говорится "*на коленках*".

Comment: данные отправляются клиенту после завершения работы пхп скрипта. средствами пхп такой вывод данных клиенту невозможен.

Comment: вот вам [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/769363/223826) запроса с сервера рандомного значения с помощью аякса.

Comment: @teran `средствами пхп такой вывод данных клиенту невозможен` возможен - с помощью сброса буфера, однако это работает не со всеми браузерами: [пример(бесконечный цикл)](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d182dd53d3a2a89d271a4d64eee7ac6a879e25a3)

Comment: @Buntibox посмотрите на пример по ссылке в комментарии выше.

Comment: @Эдуард к сожалению пример с бесконечным циклом не подходит

Comment: @Buntibox ну там цикл можно менять как угодно, я просто показал вам, как заставить скрипт отображать данные в процессе его выполнения.

Comment: @teran спасибо за пример с аяксом. Хотя он и не решает данной проблемы, но меня Вы натолкнули на мысль. А что если записывать каждое полученное число после sleep'a в xml или текстовый файл, а после эти данные аяксом выводить на страницу. Как думаете, такое осуществимо?

Comment: @Эдуард, я Вас понял. Я этот метод видел на просторах. Но он мне не подходит. Всё же спасибо Вам.

Comment: @Эдуард если мы говорим про страницу, на которой в конце еще будут всякие `</body>` то не вариант

Answer (score 1):

Только средствами PHP такой вывод невозможен.

Есть несколько путей обхода:

1. По таймеру на клиенте с помощью `Ajax` дёргать бэкэнд, где просто будет производиться какое-то действие, но это не позволит красиво хранить состояние. Но вы всегда можете его класть в `Cookies` например и не придётся класть в файл и читать его постоянно. Но лучше второй вариант
2. Воспользоваться `WebSocket` (так и загуглите "websocket php javascript"). Это позволит вам установить соединение и писать в сокет с желаемой задержкой